# How does Envoy participate in tracing using the x-request-id header?

Tags: envoyproxy, open-telemetry, opentracing, distributed-tracing, observability

Is `x-request-id` a header that was standardized in OpenTracing? Do tracing libraries such as those of OpenTelemetry or OpenTracing recognize this header and extract any tracing context from it? If not, can Envoy populate alternative headers such as the `b3` (`x-b3-traceid`, etc.) headers automatically on incoming request?

Alternatively, is bypassing Envoy completely and dealing with the tracing context propagation headers directly using OTel libraries a good alternative? In this case, Envoy would be completely agnostic to tracing.